# C++ How to initialize a std::istream* although constructor is protected

Tags: c++, stream

I want to use a class with stream-members.

My code looks like that:

```
//! pushes a Source and InputFilters into a filtering_istream
class FilterChain {
public:
    //! create an empty FilterChain
    FilterChain(){
        init();
    }

private:
    //! the stream to connect Source and InputFilters together
    io::filtering_istream* m_filteringStream;
    //! stream to use by other classes
    std::istream* m_stream;

    void init(){
        std::streambuf* streamBuffer = m_filteringStream->rdbuf();
        m_stream->rdbuf(streamBuffer);
    }
};
```

I get an error message that the std::basic_istream constructor is protected:

> /usr/include/c++/4.8.1/istream: In member function `void FilterChain::init()':
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8.1/istream:606:7: Error: `std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_istream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits]' is protected

I tried stream references as well but that caused the same error. Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT 1:

Thx to sehe I fixed it with a new init() like that:

```
void init(){
        std::streambuf* streamBuffer = m_filteringStream->rdbuf();
        m_stream = new std::istream(streamBuffer);
    }
```

Comment: Pro tips: (a) include the code that actually triggers the problem. (b) switch to en_US locale before posting compiler errors

Comment: I hope you allocate those pointers somewhere.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The compiler allocates the pointer for you... Now, the programmer's job is to initialize them properly  :/

Comment: I don't french or whatever language is that :P

Comment: @P0W I translated the German for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code shown doesn't actually contain the problem at all.

The problem is you are trying to default-construct an `istream` object somewhere (not in your question code).

You need *at least* a buffer to initialize it with:

```
std::filebuf  m_dummy;
std::istream  m_stream(&dummy);
```

Now, you can reassign the `rdbuf` like you did. See also, e.g. [How can I switch between fstream files without closing them (Simultaneous output files) - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888569/how-can-i-switch-between-fstream-files-without-closing-them-simultaneous-output/17913895#17913895)

**Update** As Dietmar just confirmed, you could just pass a `nullptr` for the `streambuf*` argument:

```
std::istream  m_stream(nullptr);
```