# Reuse of the stream iterators

Tags: c++

I have a file that need to be open multiple times during the runtime. Each time some text are appendedd into the file. Here is the code:

```
    ofstream fs;
    fs.open(debugfile, fstream::app);
    ostream_iterator<double> output(fs, " ");
    copy(starting_point.begin(), starting_point.end(), output);
    ...
    fs.open(debugfile, fstream::app);
    ostream_iterator<double> output1(fs, " ");
    copy(starting_point.begin(), starting_point.end(), output1);
```

My question is can I use one stream iterator "output" every time I open the file, e.g. some way to clean it?

Thanks

Comment: Why not put the reusable code in a function and call the function multiple times?

Comment: That' right. I can do this way.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following code:

```
ofstream fs;
fs.open(debugfile, fstream::app);
ostream_iterator<double> output(fs, " ");
copy(starting_point.begin(), starting_point.end(), output);
...
fs.open(debugfile, fstream::app);
output = ostream_iterator<double>(fs, " ");
copy(starting_point.begin(), starting_point.end(), output1);
```

Here the same variable `output` is used to store the iterator, but the iterator itself is created from scratch and assigned to this variable using `operator =`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there is nothing to do (appart reassign value) for your problem.

Just don't forget to close and clear your stream before re-open it :

```
std::ofstream file("1");
// ...
file.close();
file.clear(); // clear flags
file.open("2");
```

from : [C++ can I reuse fstream to open and write multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284775/c-can-i-reuse-fstream-to-open-and-write-multiple-files)

Comment: This does not answer the question about the iterator.